# Is it possible to write (0 < x <5) in a conditonal statement. Where x is a variable. IN PYTHON

Tags: variables, variable-assignment

I set variable x = 0. But under a while statement I changed it to x+=1. I'm trying to account for when x is in between 1 and 4 while also accounting for when x is over 4.

Comment: Maybe. What programming language?

Comment: Do you have any specific question about this? Usually, writing all kinds of code is "possible", and if there is a problem, your interpreter or compiler might tell you that